# Pandas groupby sum changes the key, why?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataset called 'event'

```
id   event_type_1   event_type_2   event_type_3
234             0              1              0
234             1              0              0
345             0              0              0
```

and I want to produce this

```
id   event_type_1   event_type_2   event_type_3
234             1              1              0
345             0              0              0
```

I tried using

```
event.groupby('id').sum()
```

but that just produced

```
id   event_type_1   event_type_2   event_type_3
1               1              1              0
2               0              0              0
```

The id has has been replaced with an incremental value starting at '1'. Why? And how do I get my desired result?

Comment: could you post an output of `print(event.columns.tolist())`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior - could you try your code against your sample data set - what does it produce?

Comment: mmmm...it works on my sample dataset...

Comment: Interestingly if I use head() on my original dataset to create a sample, it works

Comment: OK, I know what the problem was, It was sorting the result by default so it looked like the ID was reset. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`as_index=False` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [163]: event.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()
Out[163]:
    id  event_type_1  event_type_2  event_type_3
0  234             1             1             0
1  345             0             0             0
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **as_index** : boolean, default True
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index.
>   Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively
>   “SQL-style” grouped output

Comment: I thought about suggesting `as_index=False` - however, I can't see how the OP gets what they say they are given the input they've given... I can't reproduce with `id` as a column or as an index the OPs result...

Comment: @JonClements, i'm not sure i understand your point... What do you mean saying `passing False is more likely to give you something new`?

Comment: Hello MaxU, thanks for your suggestion but that also reset the index as Jon pointed out. Not sure why.

Comment: Well, then you do get what looks like an incrementing number... however, I can't see how the OP gets the `id` column as they say with the default groupby... as the column will be removed and become the index... so can't see where `id` has suddenly popped its head back into being a column... (if I'm making sense)

Comment: @user1753640 are you sure that's definitely the code you're running and the output you're getting... I'm kind of puzzled how you're getting that...

Comment: @JonClements, i get it now - thank you! I didn't notice that OP's data set isn't reproducible...

Comment: `df.groupby('Id',sort=False)`